# Elasticsearch(C# nest): Map abstract property

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a class ProductDiscount in C#. Other classes inherit from it (FlatDiscount, PercentageDiscount etc).

Storing data in Elastic seems to work but I can't read data from Elastic.

I get this error:
Could not create an instance of type ProductDiscount. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.  Path 'discount.amount', line 1, position 1098.

When I look at my index the discount is indeed storef in the collection but there's no indication of the type of the class.

Is it possible to map an abstract property in c# with the nest client?

I've tried with this mapping descriptor but with no succes:

```
mappingsDescriptor.Map<Product>(x => x
                .Properties(props => props

                    .Object<ProductDiscount>(o => o.Name(prop => prop.Discount))
                    .Object<FlatProductDiscount>(o => o.Name(prop => prop.Discount).AutoMap())
                    .Object<PercentageProductDiscount>(o => o.Name(prop => prop.Discount).AutoMap())
                    .Object<FreeProductProductDiscount>(o => o.Name(prop => prop.Discount).AutoMap())
                    .Object<QuantityProductDiscount>(o => o.Name(prop => prop.Discount).AutoMap())
                 )
            );
```

Reading is done with the ElasticClient:

```
    var result = await ElasticClient.SearchAsync<Product>(new SearchRequest(Indices.Index(index: CollectionName)));
```

Comment: Can you show how you're reading the data? You need to specify what type you want to deserialize into, you can't deserialize into an abstract class

Comment: Hi Kenneth, I updated the question. My problem is that I don't know where to define how to deserialize the Discount stuff.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that when you're deserializing it doesn't know what instance to create. Have a look here and see if you can find a workaround: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1155
Note: you might need to reindex your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution!!

I wrote a custom converter using the [JsonSubTypes package](https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes).

```
    private static JsonConverter DiscountConverter()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ProductDiscount));

        var builder = JsonSubtypesConverterBuilder
            .Of(typeof(ProductDiscount), "Type");

        assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ProductDiscount)) && !type.IsAbstract)
            .ForEach(s =>
            {
                builder.RegisterSubtype(s, s.Name);
            });

        var converter = builder
            .SerializeDiscriminatorProperty()
            .Build();

        return converter;
    }
```

My connection is set up like this

```
            var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(uris.First()));
            connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, connection, SourceSerializer());

    private static ConnectionSettings.SourceSerializerFactory SourceSerializer()
    {
        return (builtin, settings) => new JsonNetSerializer(builtin, settings,
            () => new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
                {
                    new StringEnumConverter(),
                    DiscountConverter()
                }
            });
    }
```